# How to enforce policy from maas360 mdm to my android app

Tags: android, mdm

I am trying to enforce a policy on android app and my app is not able to understand that policy.
I have written a simple code where I am asking for a string from maas360 mdm.
Following is my Android manifest code snippet:

```
<receiver android:name=".GetRestrictionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED"></action>      
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And following is my broadcast receiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Get Restriction", "on receive");
    RestrictionsManager restrictionsManager = (RestrictionsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE);
    Bundle b = restrictionsManager.getApplicationRestrictions();
    if(b.containsKey("siteName")) {
            Log.d("Get Restriction", "Site name= "+b.getString("siteName"));
    }
    //String value = intent.getStringExtra("siteName");
}
```

Following is my app_restriction xml:

```
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <restriction
        android:key="siteName"
        android:title="SiteName"
        android:restrictionType="string"
        android:defaultValue="English">
    </restriction>
</restrictions>
```

Unfortunately my broadcast is not receiving my policy from maas360 mdm.

Would you help me understand what am I missing from my code that will get me the policy?

Answer (score 0):

If you check out this page:
https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html#listen-configuration

You'll see the following -
*Note: The ACTION_APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED intent is sent only to listeners that are dynamically registered, not to listeners that are declared in the app manifest.*

I see that you are delaring the listener in the app manifest. It needs to be dynamically registered.